# Intel OneAPI 2022 - libimf.so No such file or directory - during openMPI compilation

Tags: intel-oneapi

trying to compile openmpi with intel oneapi 2022.0.1 compilers
OS is 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I got the intel compilers as follows (just to make sure I didn't mess anything up at that step)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all main"

sudo apt install intel-basekit

sudo apt install intel-hpckit
```

Configuring openmpi with:

```
./configure --prefix=${HPCX_HOME}/ompi-icc CC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/icc CXX=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/icpc F77=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort FC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort  --with-ucx=/usr --with-platform=contrib/platform/mellanox/optimized
```

my .bashrc has (root has the same .bashrc)

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin
```

After configure I do : sudo make all install and get the following error:

```
ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/../../bin/intel64/../../lib/icx-lto.so: error loading plugin: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There is no ifortvars.sh with this new version of oneAPI which seems to have solved similar issues for others in the past.

libimf.so is in:

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/itac/2021.5.0/bin/rtlib/libimf.so
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libimf.so
/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.9/pkgs/intel-cmplr-lib-rt-2022.0.1-intel_3633/lib/libimf.so
/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.9/lib/libimf.so
/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.9/envs/2022.0.1/lib/libimf.so
```

Any help and/or advice regarding compiling openmpi with recent intel compilers would be appreciated.

Comment: It was renamed to libm.lib (Windows). If you look into hex editor it has one or two of imf strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found but doubt that this is the most elegant way of doing this:

OS is 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

my .bashrc has (root has the same .bashrc)

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

created intel_libs.conf in
`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` and added the line `/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin` this is where the `libimf.so` lives.

```
sudo ldconfig
```

compiled openmpi with intel compilers fine after that using:

```
./configure --prefix={HPCX_HOME}/ompi-icc CC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/icc CXX=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/icpc F77=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort FC=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/intel64/ifort  --with-ucx=/usr --with-platform=contrib/platform/mellanox/optimized
sudo make all 
sudo make install
```

I hope this helps someone else and please let me know if there is a better way of doing this. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing similar issue not exactly. I installed the new ifort using the following command lines:

```
wget https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/18236/l_BaseKit_p_2021.4.0.3422.sh
sudo bash l_BaseKit_p_2021.4.0.3422.sh
wget https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/18211/l_HPCKit_p_2021.4.0.3347.sh
sudo bash l_HPCKit_p_2021.4.0.3347.sh
```

There is no file called *setvars.sh* inside the `source /opt/intel/oneapi/`, also while compiling any mpiifort file it is throwing me an error saying:

```
error loading plugin: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Not even sure, if this is related to this thread or not, but any further guidance would be very helpful, thanks in advance.